# Why is the syntax of testing frameworks so weird?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, syntax, tdd, bdd

I've recently started investigating on different unit-testing solutions (in JavaScript, but I guess my question is not language-specific).

The main thing I am wondering about is why the syntax is so weird in trying to imitate the human language? What is a reason behind?

For instance, an example from the [Chai](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) assertion library:

```
expect(obj).to.have.property('foo');
```

On my opinion it is far much more clear to use native means of the language to express the same thing:

```
assert(typeof obj.foo != 'undefined');
```

This is more readable for me as a developer, because I already know how `!=` and `typeof` work, and there is no need to read some additional API docs to investigate what exactly `.to.have.property()` means.

Currently I only have an impression that the syntax probably comes from the *best practices* like BDD/TDD, and a strange feeling that the idea is somehow close to what was beyond the SQL syntax.

On my opinion, instead of providing a set of 10 different functions for doing the same thing in the most preferable syntax, it would be simplier and more convenient to have a minimal set of testing-specifig functions, something like:

- test a value against being truly;
- compare two numbers/strings/objects and additionally display the diff, if those do not match;
- check if a value does not exceed a limit;
- ...

Do I miss something important? Is it implied that the tests are supposed to be partially created / evaluated by a product owner who is probably not so much of a programmer? Is the syntax just some kind of tradition for writing tests?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right that a lot of these frameworks evolved from the idea that you shouldn't need to be a programmer to understand what a test covers (and therefore, in test-first methodologies, what the software should do).

See, for example, how the [Cucumber](http://cukes.info) BDD testing framework describes their system:

> Cucumber lets software development teams describe how software should
>   behave in plain text. The text is written in a business-readable
>   domain-specific language and serves as documentation, automated tests
>   and development-aid - all rolled into one format.

[A piece by Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BusinessReadableDSL.html) from back in 2008 is referenced by the Cucumber page, and provides what is presumably the justification for making a non-native domain-specific language (DSL) for testing:

> If business people are able to look at the DSL code and understand it,
>   then we can build a deep and rich communication channel between
>   software development and the underlying domain.

That all said, I've yet to see or be a part of a team where the testing language (and it's usually a stretch to call this syntax a DSL) was actually used by both software developers and "business people", but perhaps there are environments where this is more common. The good news is that most of the common testing frameworks are flexible enough to support tests using any syntax you like, including your own preferred native/idiomatic dialect, so you're free to eschew the seemingly common practice of `this.should.be.equal.to.that` and just say `assert(this === that)`.

Comment: I can hardly beleive the idea might work at all. The requirements of a customer are too far from what is supposed to be tested (at least at the level of unit-tests). The actual tests written by a developer mostly verify the substances that do not make too much sence for a business. Customers may be curious about acceptance / system tests, and today this is mostly GUI which is tested manually (until the task is to create something computing-related with an API, like a library, but in this case the customer should obviously be capable of writing code).

Answer (score 1):

> `assert(typeof obj.foo != 'undefined');`

There is a critical problem with this approach: it does not produce a good message on failure. In this specific case, the only failure is the case where obj.foo == undefined, but in general you want the test framework to be able to report *how things differed from expectation*.

For this reason, your “minimal set of testing-specific functions” is actually quite large. Fancy structures like you mention help organize things so that it's not a massive list of functions and in particular you can avoid redundancy from needing both “assertContains” and “assertNotContains” and so on (whose implementations would be very similar) and instead have a "not" modifier.

Making the structure of the test assertions then look like English is popular with some people, but I don't care to defend it myself — I'm only pointing out here that there is a reason for complexity in a test-assertion framework.

Comment: I am not against the advanced solutions providing another "not" modifier for those who wish to use it. But I already have one, that is `!` in the programming language, and I don't need anything else. Having said this, I expect that there should be simplier (yet popular) testing solutions. But almost every testing framework duplicates the entities implying this is the correct approach.

The "minimal list" of needed functions which I wrote in my question should actually cover all the cases I can imagine.